# How can I call a function with promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Here is my code:

```
var gblink = require('./getbloglinks');

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     var getLinks = gblink.getBlogLinks("www.example.com");
     resolve(getLinks);

}).then(function (data) {
     console.log("here");
     console.log(data);
     return false;
})
```

`gblink.getBlogLinks()` is a function which gets a URL and returns all links in that page *(after a short time)*. When I run my code, immediately `console.log("here");` will be printed and then `console.log(data);` will be printed as `undefined`.

Anyway how can I make that promise waiting until the result of `getBlogLinks()` returns?

Noted that when I call `gblink.getBlogLinks()` function manually, it works as well, it just takes a while and all I need to do now is implementing a waiting system for that function.

---

Here is `gblink.getBlogLinks()`:

```
const NN = require('nightmare');

exports.getBlogLinks = function (data){

    const n = NN({show:true});

    n.goto(data)

    .evaluate(() => {

        var data = document.querySelectorAll("a[target='_blank']");

        arr = [];
        i=0;
        Array.from(data).forEach( function(x){
            arr[i] = x.href;
            i++;
        });
        return arr;
    })
    .then((data) => {
        return n.end(data);


    })
}
```

Comment: You need to call resolve in gblink.getBlogLinks callback

Comment: is gblink.getBlogLinks() itself a promise ? then you have to implement then() on it.

Comment: @codeteq No it is not promise. it is nightmare.

Comment: can you share the implementation of getbloglinks()?

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay Sure ..

Comment: do you have the permission of changing the implementation of getbloglinks()?

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay TBH I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getBlogLinks`  is not returning the promise. Doing that should solve the problem.

```
const NN = require('nightmare');

exports.getBlogLinks = function (data){

    const n = NN({show:true});

    return n.goto(data)

        .evaluate(() => {

            var data = document.querySelectorAll("a[target='_blank']");

            arr = [];
            i=0;
            Array.from(data).forEach( function(x){
                arr[i] = x.href;
                i++;
            });
            return arr;
        })
        .then((data) => {
            n.end(data);
            return data;
        })
};
```

Edited:

```
var gblink = require('./getbloglinks');

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     var getLinks = gblink.getBlogLinks("www.example.com");
     console.log(getLinks);//========= Here You will get Pending promise =========
     resolve(getLinks);

}).then(function (data) {
     console.log("here");
     console.log(data);//========= Here You will get the array=========
     return false;
})
```

Edited2:

```
var gblink = require('./getbloglinks');

/*
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var getLinks = gblink.getBlogLinks("www.example.com");
    console.log(getLinks);//========= Here You will get Pending promise =========
    resolve(getLinks);

})*/
//Below is recommended way to chain the promise, avoid promise constructor, if not needed
gblink.getBlogLinks("www.example.com")
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log("here");
        console.log(data);//========= Here You will get the array=========
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: @MartinAJ Welcome :)

Comment: As a note, your solution doesn't work totally. It will work if I write `console.log(data)` in the `.then()` block of `getBlogLinks` function. But still `getBlogLinks` function doesn't return the result to the promise in the main page.

Comment: @MartinAJ Can you `console.log(getLinks)` and check if its a promise of not?

Comment: In where should I write `console.log(getLinks)`? in the `resolve` block on the promise?

Comment: @MartinAJ  `var getLinks = gblink.getBlogLinks("www.example.com");
console.log(getLinks);
resolve(getLinks);`. See in first code snippet

Comment: I don't know what `n.end(data);` does and I guess it is wrong. I seen it somewhere in the internet and pasted there.

Comment: @MartinAJ No problem. I have edited my code. It will work fine now.

Comment: Now the result of `var getLinks = gblink.getBlogLinks("www.example.com"); console.log(getLinks); resolve(getLinks);` is `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Actually the expected result is that array. I need to get that array *(which is exists in the `.then()` block of `getBlogLinks` function)* in the main promise.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `getBlogLinks()` is a function implemented in your scope of development.

So, what is happening, in your current code of `getBlogLInks()` the response is getting returned only when there is a response. But the way you call it, it's synchronous.

Your `getBlogLinks` need to be wrapped in a promise.

```
getBlogLinks(data) {
  return new Promise( function(resolve,reject) {
      ....all your function code
      .then(data) {
          resolve(data); 
       }
  });
  }
```

then use `getBlogLinks().then` and you will have your answer

Comment: Hey Aseem. I think this solution may not work. `resolve(data)` in your code will not resolve the right `data` but rather, the `data` received by `getBlogLinks` as argument.

Comment: oh that might be a misunderstanding let me correct it